# Justify „polar coordinates“ with the change of variables formula for differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, polar-coordinates, change-of-variable, pullback

For $m\in\mathbb N$ define the ball $B^m \overset{\text{Def.}}=\{ p\in \mathbb R^m:\|p\|_2<1\}$ and the sphere $S^{m-1} \overset{\text{Def.}}= \partial B^m\subset\mathbb R^m$. I want to prove the following statement using the [change of variables formula for differential forms](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChangeofVariablesTheorem.html) in order to strengthen my understanding of the Theorem:

> **Statement. (Polar coordinates)** We have $$\tag{*}\int_{B^m} 1 = \int_0^1 r^{m-1} \int_{S^{m-1}} 1\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dr.$$

**My idea:** Consider the smooth manifold $M=[0,1)\times S^{m-1}$ and the smooth function $f:M\to B^m, (r,x)\mapsto r x$. Then change of variables gives $$\int_{B^m} 1=\int_{B^m} \mathrm dx^1\land\dots\land\mathrm dx^m=\int_M f^*(dx^1\land\dots\land\mathrm dx^m ),$$
so I would just have to prove that the pullback $f^*(dx^1\land\dots\land\mathrm dx^m )$ is $r^{m-1}\mathrm dr\land\dots$. How can I do this?

**Also:** How can I extend this method when I replace $1$ in (*) by a, say smooth, function $J:B^m\to\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: **HINT**: What is the surface area $(m-1)$-form on the unit sphere, in terms of cartesian coordinates? Use the product rule and expand the wedge product.

Comment: Regarding your second question, that's just the usual change of variables formula. Pull back $J$, i.e., insert $J\circ f$.

Comment: @TedShifrin It is (to avoid confusion I will use $y$ instead of $x$) $$\omega=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j-1}y^j dy^{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge \widehat{dy^{j}}\wedge\cdots dy^{m}.$$ Do I get $f^*(\mathrm dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\mathrm dx^m)=\mathrm dr\wedge\omega$ ?

Comment: No, you get the $r^{m-1}$ factor, just as you desire!

Comment: @TedShifrin For example for $m=2$ I get $$f^*(\mathrm dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\mathrm dx^m)=(y^1\,\mathrm dr +r\,\mathrm dy^1)\wedge(y^2\,\mathrm dr+r\,\mathrm dy^2)=y^1 r\,\mathrm dr\wedge\mathrm dy^2+r y^2\,\mathrm dy^1\wedge\mathrm dr+r^2\,\mathrm dy^1\wedge\mathrm dy^2$$ and $$r^{m-1}\,\mathrm dr\wedge\omega=y^1r\,\mathrm dr\wedge\mathrm dy^2+ry^2\,\mathrm dy^1\wedge\mathrm dr$$ so there is a disconcordance (the $r^2\,\mathrm dy^1\wedge\mathrm dy^2$)? 

Comment: No discord! $dy^1\wedge dy^2=0$, as this is a $2$-form on $S^1$. (If you prefer, the equation $\sum (y^i)^2 = 1$ gives you a linear dependence among $dy^i$, $i=1,\dots,m$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh right! (There are only $1$-forms on $S^1$ of course .) Still one more question: Take the "global map" $$\phi:S^1\to[0,2\pi[,(\cos t,\sin t)\mapsto t$$ (it is not really a map because of diffeomorphism issues at $0$ and $2\pi$ but I'll ignore that). Then the abstract definition gives for real $k$, $$\mathrm dy^1\vert_{(\cos t,\sin t)}(k\partial_\phi\vert_{(\cos t,\sin t)})=k (y^1\circ\phi^{-1})^\prime(t)=-k\sin t.$$ Similarly, $\mathrm dy^2\vert_{(\cos t, \sin t)}(k\partial_\phi\vert_{(\cos t,\sin t)})=k\cos t$. Now my question is: How does this correspond to $2\sum dy^i = 0$ ?

Comment: Oops. You mean $\sum y^i\,dy^i = 0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh now it makes sense, in a moment of mental blackout it seems I forgot about the product rule. Thanks, I might write an answer to my question in the next week or so (I am pretty busy at the moment )

Comment: LOL, most people would prefer that I had just posted a perfect answer to start with, but I honestly think you learned more this way. If you end up wanting me to post, let me know.

Comment: @TedShifrin Go ahead if you want. But I'll try it myself too when I have the time so I won't accept your answer before in a week or so . By the way, this is a question in the spirit of a course from last semester, the continuation of which I am following now. Even though there are many powerful&abstract results in these courses that go way beyond the content of my question here, I think it is still good for me to try some simple concrete examples as well to get familiar with them. So indeed I learned something from our discussion here in the comments .

Comment: @TedShifrin With a little delay I have now answered my question, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that any differential form is, by definition, an alternating tensor field. Therefore, the pullback $$f^*(J\, \mathrm dx^1\land\dots\land\mathrm dx^m),$$ by [LeeSM13; Corollary 12.28], is equal to, with the notation $(r,y)=(r,y^1,\dots, y^{m-1})$, $$J\circ f\, \mathrm d(x^1\circ f)\land\dots\land\mathrm d(x^m\circ f).$$

(Henceforth, as is usual in differential geometry, we will also use $r,y^1,\dots, y^{m-1}$ to denote the respective projection operators from $[0,1[\times S^{m-1}$ into $\mathbb R$.)

Now for each $k\in\{1,\dots, m\}$, we have $$x^k\circ f:M\to[0,1[, \  (r, y)\mapsto r y^k.$$ By [LeeSM13; pages 62, 63 or formula (11.11)], we thus have ("formula for the total derivative") $$\mathrm d(x^k\circ f)=\frac{\partial(r y^k)}{\partial r}\,\mathrm dr+\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{\partial (r y^k)}{\partial y^i}\,\mathrm dy^i=y^k\,\mathrm dr+r\,\mathrm dy^k.$$

Therefore, $$f^*(\mathrm dx^1\land\dots\land\mathrm dx^m)=\bigwedge_{k=1}^m (y^k\,\mathrm dr+r\,\mathrm dy^k).$$

**Claim.** In the above setting, for any $m\in\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}$, we have $$\bigwedge_{k=1}^m (y\,\mathrm dr+r\,\mathrm dy^k)=r^{m-1}\mathrm dr\wedge\omega,$$ where (for notation see [LeeSM13; Pages 315 and following]) $$\omega=\omega(m)=\sum_{j=1}^{m}(-1)^{j-1} y^j\,\mathrm dy^1\wedge\dots\wedge \mathrm dy^{j-1}\wedge\mathrm dy^{j+1}\wedge\dots\wedge\mathrm dy^{m}\in\Gamma(\Lambda^{m-1}(S^{m-1})).$$

---

In particular, once we have chosen the claim, we have proven the desired statement in the question, since $\omega$ is the volume form of $S^{m-1}$ by [Kö02; Page 436].

---

*Proof of Claim.* Note first that $\mathrm dr\wedge\mathrm dr=0$. Now consider $$\bigwedge_{k=1}^m (y\,\mathrm dr+r\,\mathrm dy^k).$$ When fully expanding the wedge, if we take any product which contains $\mathrm dr$ at least twice, then that term will be equal to $0$. If the term contains $\mathrm dr$ not at all, then it must be equal to some function times $\mathrm dy^1\wedge\dots\wedge\mathrm dy^{m}$, which is also equal to $0$, as $$\sum_{k=1}^m y^k\mathrm dy^k = 0,$$ as can be derived from $$\sum_{k=1}^m (y^k)^2=1.$$

Therefore, we are just left with $$\bigwedge_{k=1}^m (y\,\mathrm dr+r\,\mathrm dy^k)=\sum_{k=1}^m r^{m-1} \,\mathrm dy^1\wedge\dots\wedge\mathrm d y^{k-1}\wedge\mathrm dr\wedge\mathrm dy^{k+1}\wedge\dots\wedge \mathrm dy^m=\mathrm dr\wedge\omega.$$ $\square$

---

#### Literature

1. LeeSM13: John Lee, *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. Second Edition, 2012/2013.
2. Kö02: Konrad Königsberger, *Analysis 2*. Fourth Edition, 2002.

---

*Note:* I lost a lot of time in the proof since I first wanted to go by induction, but there is the nasty detail (lost in my notation) that $$\mathrm dy^1\vert_{S^m}\wedge\dots\wedge \mathrm dy^m\vert_{S^m}=0$$ but $$\mathrm dy^1\vert_{S^{m+1}}\wedge\dots\wedge \mathrm dy^m\vert_{S^{m+1}}\neq 0.$$